# $ref tag in Swagger

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-ui

How do I use a $ref tag in Swagger to refer to a definition in a different file?

All the examples in Swagger Editor defines anything referenced by the $ref tag in the *same* file.

For e.g. in the Uber API example available on Swagger Editor, it has a number of references like "#/definitions/Product" and "#/definitions/Errors". However both are defined in the *same* file in the "definitions" section.

If I wanted to define "Product" or "Errors" in a *different* file, how would I go about doing it? Which tags will the definition file contain? Does it need to have ALL the mandatory flags for Swagger (like **paths**)? Also, how would the definition be rendered on the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
"parameters": [
 {
    "name": "cat",
    "in": "body",
    "description": "The JSON payload for the new cat",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
       "$ref": "cat-new.json"
    }
  }
]
```

and cat-new.json has the following defined:

```
{
  "description":"An adorable cat",
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "name":{
       "type":"string",
       "description":"The name given to this cat by the adoption staff",
       "minLength":3,
       "maxLength":15
    },
    "colour":{
       "type":"string",
       "description":"The colour of the cat's fur",
       "enum":[
          "black",
          "tan",
          "ginger",
          "blue",
          "white"
       ]
    },
    "toys":{
       "type":"array",
       "description":"The favourite toys of the cat",
       "items":{
          "type":"string"
       },
       "maxItems":3,
       "uniqueItems":true
    }
  }
}
```

Ref:

1) https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1145

2) https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#relative-schema-file-example

Comment: Thank you @wing328. I now understand how to refer a definition file. I am assuming I would need to have it in the same folder as the main file. Will the Swagger editor/Any Swagger Documentation portal read it from the local drive and display it embedded within the definition?

Comment: I'm not sure how swagger-editor handles $ref to local files or URLs. Please open an "issue" at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues to find out more.